# How to convert to C# a code to calculate a Distance and Bearing from google maps api

Tags: java, c#, google-maps, google-location-services

When I'm using Google Maps on Android I create a method to take a point A and calculate if it is inside of an area of 1km to the point B :

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(centerLatitude, centerLongitude, testLatitude, 
testLongitude, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0];
boolean isWithin10km = distanceInMeters < 10000;
```

But I need to to this inside of my API, so I send a Location(Lat,Long) to my Server, I get a list of locations and try to make a match and them return something, the problem is, how to "unwrap" the code so I could switch to C#!

I founf the implementation of it, but it has some proper classes that I'm sure it doesn't exist in C#! [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java)

Comment: Looks like you should just rewrite the Location.java file into C#?

Comment: Well, there's a lot of things going on inside of Location.java

Comment: Most likely that your server receives json serialized string ("wraped") with latlon coordinates. It can be deserialized in whatever you want. For example, you can use [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) with its classes.

Comment: @RusArt The only thing that I want to send to my API is my Lat and Long, so there I could calculate this.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend that you use the assembly `Sysetem.Device.Location` (you can download a nugetpackage if you don't have it on your machine from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Device.Location.Portable/)).

Then you can do the following using the `GeoCoordinate` class:

```
var geo1=new GeoCoordinate(centerLatitude, centerLongitude);
var geo2=new GeoCoordinate(testLatitude, testLongitude):
var result=geo1.GetDistanceTo(geo2);
```

For more information, please visit the documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx).